# Ability to create child resource with admin-on-rest

Tags: admin-on-rest

Is there anyway to create child resource with admin-on-rest? For instance when adding a comment to post we want to call

```
POST posts/1/comments
```

instead of select the post id when creating comments as in ReferenceInput

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to migrate to react-admin then it is at least possible. Might work also on admin-on-rest. Take a look on this https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#prefilling-a-create-record

Comment: I did check the link, couldn't figure out if there's any related information about child resources there.